# slideToggle, hidden or visible if statement

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to work out an hide/show function according to, if the div's are hidden or not. My code looks like this:

```
    //postInbox/outbox/savedbox show all/hide all
$('.postBoxShowAll').click(function(){
    $('.postBoxContent').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        if($(this).is(':hidden')){
            $('.postBoxShowAll').html('Show all');
        }else{
            $('.postBoxShowAll').html('Hide all');
        }
    });
});
//
```

*** UPDATE ***

This worked:

```
    //postInbox/outbox/savedbox show all/hide all
$('.postBoxShowAll').click(function(){
    $('.postBoxContent').slideToggle('fast', function(){
        if($('.postBoxContent').is(':visible')){
            $('.postBoxShowAll').html('Hide all');
        }else{
            $('.postBoxShowAll').html('Show all');
        }
    });
});
//
```

But for some reason, it won't change the text. It slides just fine. How come?

Comment: It works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/FYShk/

Comment: I really don't get why this won't work for me. But the UPDATE in my question works for me.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

may be try  this

```
$('.postBoxShowAll').click(function() {
    $('.postBoxContent').slideToggle('fast', function() {
        if ($('.postBoxContent').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.postBoxShowAll').html('Show all');
        } else {
            $('.postBoxShowAll').html('Hide all');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's working now. I just did a :visible instead of hidden. I'll let you have the answer correct.